# How convert a few IF into one LOOP

Tags: java, android

I want to convert my multiple IF statements into one LOOP.

Can you tell me is it possible and how can I do that?

```
                    if (howManyTimes == 2) {
                        allHours = setTime1.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime2.getText().toString();
                    } else if (howManyTimes == 3) {
                        allHours = setTime1.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime2.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime3.getText().toString();
                    } else if (howManyTimes == 4) {
                        allHours = setTime1.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime2.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime3.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime4.getText().toString();
                    } else if (howManyTimes == 5) {
                        allHours = setTime1.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime2.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime3.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime4.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime5.getText().toString();
                    } else if (howManyTimes == 6) {
                        allHours = setTime1.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime2.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime3.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime4.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime5.getText().toString() + ", " +
                                setTime6.getText().toString();
                    }
```

Comment: Hint: I'm not sure what `setTimeX` is, but you might benefit from it being in an array.

Comment: @JoeC setTime is a TextView

Comment: You can make an array of textview rather than individual variables

Comment: Put your setTimeX objects into array, say times[], and then for(int i = 0; i < howManyTimes; i++) {allHours = times[i].getText().toString(); if (i < howManyTimes - 1) allHours += ", ";}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add group all thoose setTimeN objects into an array you can go like this:

```
ArrayList<TextView> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add(setTime1);
array.add(setTime2);
//Add all your setTime files

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < howmanytimes-1; i++) {
     sb.append(array.get(i).getText().toString() + ", ");
}

sb.append(array.get(howmanytimes-1).getText().toString();

String allHours = sb.toString();
```

You can also use the foreach variant:

```
for (TextView t: array) {
     sb.append(t.getText().toString() + ", ");
}
```

In this last case you have to remove the last `", "`